# What does exclamation mark "!." after an object property means in Javascript

Tags: javascript, syntax

In a JavaScript (TypeScript) code I saw this syntax, with the exclamation point after an object property:

```js
const myObject = {
 key: something!.else,
}
```

I guess it's some kind of condition such as `something?.else`, but I can't find a reference.

What is the name of it and what does it mean? From which ECMA Script version does it come from?

Comment: I thought it as a JavaScript syntax not TypeScript, that's why I didn't found it. Thanks anyway!

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator